# Can't var_dump, echo, or print_r string, but can use string, and can output individual characters

Tags: php, xml

I have a string inside a variable (Made short for demonstration)

```
$xml = '<xml ect ect ect...';
```

This line of code below

```
var_dump($xml);
```

Returns this output

```
string(2715) " "
```

But this line of code

```
var_dump($xml[0]);
```

Returns this output

```
string(1) "<"
```

I am building the xml with this function, one line at a time.

```
protected static function _addLine(&$xml, $string, $padding = 0)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < (int)$padding; $i++) {
        $xml .= '   ';
    }
    $xml .= $string . chr(10);
}
```

The xml variable can be used, altered, and I can even create a file with the expected content.

```
$xmlFile = fopen('example.xml, 'w');
fwrite($xmlFile, $xml);
fclose($xmlFile);
```

I am unable to output the `$xml` variable to the page however. I've tried, `echo`, `var_dump`, `print_r`, and `$debug = $xml; echo $debug;`. None of these have worked. Why is this variable not outputting?

Comment: Check the Inspect Element on your browser because the content is being dumped, but the browser is processing the XML tag.

Comment: let me guess... `echo htmlentities($xml);` will show you string?

Comment: Use `var_dump` as you are already, and do a `view page source` to see output

Comment: I noticed right after I asked, thanks for the help, and sorry about the bother. I didn't find a relevant result on stack, hopefully this will be found next time this issue is encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually, on the page, you won't see the xml, but if you use inspect element, you will see the elements are there. The browser is interpreting the `xml` string as `html` elements. To see in a browser, escape the html characters.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($xml);
```